# Im currently trying to make a simple game using html and css only (might have some java but barely any) and I can't seem to put 5tables side by side

Tags: html, css

[This is what I'm trying to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHYfn.png)

There are a couple reasons on why I'm having trouble making this, I can't put all of these tables in one big table since that will make the main box able to go through all the obstacles.

Here's the code for a simple level to show what I'm trying to do exactly:

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
<title> Level 1 </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Mohanned_Project.css" />
<style>
body {
background: blue;
background-size: cover;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<th>
<img src="Obstacle_1.png" height="285px" width="1400px">
<img src="Box.png" id="Goat" align="left">
<img src="Win.png" align="right">
</th>
</tr>
</table>
<table style="padding: 0px 1300px 1300px 0px;">
<tr>
<th>
<img src="Obstacle_1.png" height="285px" width="1400px">
</th>
</tr>
</table>



</body>
</html>
```

Css:

```
#Goat {
position: sticky;
top: 300px;
left: 10px;
right: 10px;
}

#Goat_2 {
position: sticky;
top: 10px;
left: 10px;
right: 10px;

}

.btn{
   color: #fff;
   border: none;
   margin: 5px;
   padding: 10px 8px;
   font-size: 20px;
   font-weight: 600;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   letter-spacing: 2px;
   cursor: pointer;
   border-radius: 10px;
   transition: 0.4s;
   transition-property: box-shadow;
}

.btn-primary{
font-size: 31px;
}
```

and heres the result: [When you move the screen, the red box sticks to the borders and moves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/796Df.png)

I would really apprecciate advice on how do I set up the 2nd level since I've been trying for an hour and can't seem to figure it out

Comment: I forgot to mention, the buttons in the css have nothing to do with the code, I have them for the page where you access each of these levels

Comment: Make a simple reproduction here or on codepen. Also, this can be very easily achieved by css flexbox, rather than with table.

Answer (score 0):

Stop using tables. Use divs. and flexbox.

```css
.cafeteria {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.first-row {}

.table-row {
  display: flex;
}

.table {
  width: 40px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: brown;
}

.small-table {
  align-self: flex-end;
  width: 40px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: brown;
}

.small-table.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.small-table.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="cafeteria">
  <div class="first-row">
    <div class="small-table blue"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table"></div>
    <div class="small-table"></div>
    <div class="table"></div>
    <div class="small-table"></div>
    <div class="table"></div>
    <div class="small-table"></div>
    <div class="table"></div>
    <div class="small-table green"></div>
    <div class="table">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you try putting position sticky in your CSS Code, And tell me if you can move the red box to the green box by scrolling right/down?